# django template tags with async view

Tags: python, django

As soon as I add async in front of a view, my template which contains `{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}` causes a **SynchronousOnlyOperation**, You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.

The error only occurs when a user is logged in, hence is_authenticated==True. What am I not getting here?

view

```
async def test(request):
    return render(request, 'test.html')
```

template, test.html

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
<script>
  const usr = "{{user}}";
</script>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the current user is not authenticated, `request.user` is an `AnonymousUser`, so `is_authenticated` is just false. However, when `request.user` is an actual user, it needs to check through the ORM if the user is authenticated. The ORM is synchronous (except in a few situations), so this doesn't work in an async context. To make this work, use `sync_to_async` in the view:

```py
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
async def test(request):
    return render(request, 'test.html', {"is_authenticated": await sync_to_async(lambda: request.user.is_authenticated)()})
```

And in `test.html`:

```html
{% if is_authenticated %}
<script>
  const usr = "{{user}}";
</script>
{% endif %}
```

I know it's a pain, but for now it's the only way. Here's hoping that Django will add asynchronous support ORM-wide in the next release.

Comment: sync_to_async cannot be awaited apparently, despite seeing it in the documentation... "object SyncToAsync can't be used in 'await' expression". Removing the await then causes the same SynchronousOnlyOperation error to trigger on the const usr = "{{user}}" portion, meaning we need to again use sync_to_async for each django template variable. So now, without the await, is the sync_to_async truly asynchronous?

Comment: @noob112233 Sorry, forgot to actually call the function. it works now.

Comment: I had just found that too, thanks. Marked as solution.

Answer (score 1):

As of Django 5.0, they have made it a little easier to access the user from an async context without the need of a wrapper or doing any lambda functions, though there is a small caveat (see below).

You can now access the user by simply doing:

```
async def test(request):
    user = await request.auser()
    is_auth = user.is_authenticated
    return render(request, 'test.html', {'is_authenticated': is_auth})
```

Or you could leave it at just the user if you want the whole object. The caveat is make sure you call `.auser()`. That got me the first time trying to use it, it is a method on the HttpRequest object, not an attribute like `user`.

From there, you can proceed how you were before.