# django layout template tags with async view

Tags: python, django, asynchronous

I'm trying to access my template `page.html` from an async view.
My question is very similar to the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73667396/django-template-tags-with-async-view).
Yet, the difference is that `page.html` extends a `layout.html` layout.
The SynchronousOnlyOperation is triggered by the presence of `{{request.user}}` I'm using in the layout, not directly in `page.html`.

`layout.html`

```
   <span class="d-flex flex-row dashboard-settings-icon mx-2">
        <i class="bi bi-person-circle"></i>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a
              class="dropdown-toggle"
              href="#"
              id="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink"
              role="button"
              data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-expanded="false"
            >
              {{request.user}}
            </a>
            <ul
              class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark"
              aria-labelledby="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink"
            >
              <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'logout_user' %}"
                  ><i class="bi bi-box-arrow-left"></i> Logout</a
                >
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
   </span>
```

`page.html`

```
{% extends 'layouts/layout.html' %} {% block content %} {% load static %}
   <form action={% url 'account:upload' %} method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    # form
   </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

The view

```
async def upload(request):
     if request.POST:
        form = ModelFormClass(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
           if request.FILES:
              # File handling
              results = await process_data()
           await form.save()
           return render(request, "pages/account/results.html", {"form":form, "results":results})
        else:
           return render(request, "pages/account/page.html", {"form":form})
      
     return render(request, "pages/account/page.html", {"form":ModelFormClass})
```

As there's no view for displaying the layout itself, I tried the following in the view responsible of `page.html` display:

```
async def upload(request):
 if request.POST:
    form = ModelFormClass(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
       if request.FILES:
          # File handling
          results = await process_data()
       await form.save()
       return render(request, "pages/account/results.html", {"form":form, "results":results})
    else:
       return render(request, "pages/account/page.html", {"form":form, "user":await sync_to_async(lambda: request.user)()})

 return render(request, "pages/account/page.html", {"form":ModelFormClass, "user":await sync_to_async(lambda: request.user)()})
```

and replacing `{{request.user}}` in `layout.html` by `{{user}}`. I'm still getting the `SynchronousOnlyOperation` exception error `You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.`

I've read in my searches, that `{{request.user}}` can be accessed thanks to context processors in `settings.py` file :

```
TEMPLATES = [
 {
    "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
    "DIRS": ["templates"],
    "APP_DIRS": True,
    "OPTIONS": {
        "context_processors": [
            "django.template.context_processors.debug",
            "django.template.context_processors.request",
            "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
            "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
        ],
    },
 }, ]
```

Please, what am I not getting or doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

In django 5.0 there is request.auser for async
([ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.auser)). Probably they added it for context-processors too

Comment: this looks like a comment and not the answer.